# jQuery loop through input and select fields

Tags: jquery

I want to loop through all my `input` elements and `select` elements in one loop but this doesn't work.

```
$('#blockProperties :input :select').each(function () {
    // do something
});
```

When I only loop through one of the two it does work.

Comment: The problem was that `:select` doesn't work, by changing it to `select` it worked both in my way as Box9's and michelgotta's way. Thanks

Comment: Using `:input` will give you all `form` elements like radiobuttons, checkboxes, textareas, inputs. There is no `:select` selector in jQuery.

Comment: And another thing learned today, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selector should be:

```
'#blockProperties :input, #blockProperties select'
```

What you have is looking for a select **inside** an input.

Answer (score 5):

The manual says [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) *"selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."* So just do:

```
$('#blockProperties :input').each(function () {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#blockProperties input, #blockProperties select').each(function () {
    // do something
});
```

or (for all form elements):

```
$('#blockProperties :input').each(function () {
    // do something
});
```